# Error in connecting to Access database from Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I have to create excel macro which fetches from access database and update appropriate columns in excel worksheet.
I have never done VBA programming before, i am just able to write a code to connect to the database which is giving me error saying "Error in From clause".

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Users\Xprts8\Documents\shipping.accdb;" & _
"User Id=admin;Password="

conn.Open (strcon)

qry = "SELECT * FROM shipping-table"
rs.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset

rs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

can anybody help me with the following problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shipping-table` is not a valid table name in an SQL statement (because of the hyphen) unless its escaped thusly:

`SELECT * FROM [shipping-table]`